# Exception this freezable cannot be freezed while using DiscreteObjectKeyFrame

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have here some buttons that are inside a stackpanelin a wpf, the buttons have slightly curved corners. I want that there will be an animation that will turn the buttons into a circle if the mouse hovers over them. However this code here throws "System.InvalidOperationException, This Freezable cannot be frozen."

```
<StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard Name="CurveStoryboard" Storyboard.TargetProperty ="Button" >
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Border  CornerRadius="30,30,30,30" ></Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: There is no `Button` property in a StackPanel, so the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` won't work.

Comment: What do I need to change in order to make it work ?